# How to draw features on OpenLayers geoserver raster source?

Tags: openlayers, wms

I can successfully draw a point on an OpenLayers map with source `new ol.source.Vector({features: features});`. However, I am trying to show these points on the raster source that I am pulling through geoserver using `ol.source.TileWMS`

Everytime I try to add a point on the raster source it does not appear. I can select the point by hovering over it on the raster source. However, it does not appear on the raster source. I need to show something to indicate the clicked point. What can I do ?

The following are the relevant parts of my code :

```
           draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
                  source: vectorsource,
                  type: ("Point"),
                  wrapX: true
              });

           draw.on('drawend', function (event) {
            var style= new ol.style.Style({
                          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                              }),
                          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                color: '#ffcc33',
                                width: 2
                              }),
                          image: new ol.style.Circle({
                                radius: 7,
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                  color: '#ffcc33'
                                })
                              }),
                          text: new ol.style.Text({
                                text: ++counter+"",
                                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                  color: '#fff'
                                })
                              })
                                 });


var vectorsource = new ol.source.Vector({features: features});

var rasterSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/system/wms',
              params: {'LAYERS': 'system:ia-soil', 'TILED': true},
              serverType: 'geoserver',
              crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
                });
```

The images below shows the effect in greater detail: 
[image: Notice How point 2 appears on the map , but point 2 is overridden by the raster source.]

Notice How point 2 appears on the map , but point 1 is overridden by the raster source. The point 1 is there you can select it, by hovering over it. I want to show point one location on the raster source. How can I do that?

---

The code that shows loading layers to the map.

```
map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults().extend
          ([  new ol.control.LayerPopup(),new ol.control.FullScreen()]),
        interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
          new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom()
        ]),
        layers: [raster,vectorsource,rastersource],// raster is just OSM layer.
        target: 'map',
        view: view
      });
```

This is how I am loading my map.

Comment: the relevant part of your code is where you add the layers to the map, which is missing but you probably put the vector layer below the raster

Comment: Hello! I just added the map to show how I am adding my layers.

Comment: and it fixed the problem by rearranging the layer. You just saved me a long night work. Please add it as an answer to I can accept it as an answert]